# Window.open popup blocking issue on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open two url on one button click. I have used window.open method but its blocking popup.

On button click I want to open this two url. but it is not working as per need.

Here is my code for script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function(){ 

    var newUrl = 'https://red.kngtraxx.com/5d2fe6a5180ed400010de4be?fname=' + fname + '&email=' + email + '&clickid=' + clickid + '&pid=' + pid + '&phone=' + phone + '&sub1=' + sub1 + '&edulevel=' + edulevel + '&military=' + military + '&study=' + study + "&ip=" + ip + "&zip=" + zipcode;

    var newTabUrl = 'https://red2.kngtraxx.com/5d2fe70e180ed400010de4c0?fname=' + fname + '&email=' + email + '&clickid=' + clickid + '&pid=' + pid + '&phone=' + phone + '&sub1=' + sub1 + '&edulevel=' + edulevel + '&military=' + military + '&study=' + study + "&ip=" + ip + "&zip=" + zipcode;

    alert(newUrl);
    alert(newTabUrl);

    $('#lp-pom-button-826').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(newUrl, "_self");
      window.open(newTabUrl)
    //setTimeout(() => , 1000);
  });

  }, 2000);

});
</script>

I want to solve popup blocking issue
```

Comment: If browser blocking your popup then you need to deal with [browser popup settings](https://www.isc.upenn.edu/how-to/configuring-your-web-browser-allow-pop-windows).

Comment: If the browser has any popup blocker, then the problem has no solution.

Comment: @krish, I can not tell every customer to set browser settings. No one will set that settings

Comment: @Pia I can understand your situation but the reality is its all about user to choose if they want to allow a site to show popup or not. There is no way in javascript to turn off popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, `window.open()` will work for one tab, otherwise, it will be blocked.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="https://google.com" onclick="location.href='https://yahoo.com'" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**: Added the below based on OP's need
In case you have dynamic URLs, use a script to update the attributes of  dynamically using a function and you are set:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="myLink" href="https://google.com" onclick="location.href='https://yahoo.com'" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
    <script>
        function makeDynamicUrlsAndChangeLink() {
            var link = document.getElementById("myLink");
            var param1 = "val1", param2 = "val2";
            var link1 = "https://google.com" + "?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2;
            var link2 = "location.href='https://vmware.com" + "?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2 + "'";
            link.setAttribute("href", link1);
            link.setAttribute("onclick", link2);
        }
        makeDynamicUrlsAndChangeLink();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can not use html href tag and onclick javascript method. I need to pass variables in url. so can not use href or onclick method.

Comment: @Pia You can still use <a> even if you have dynamic URLs. Use Javascript function to dynamically change the attributes from your code. See the sample appended to the answer. Copy and try it yourself and let me know.

Comment: @Pia I hope your purpose of opening two dynamic URLs is resolved. You can always make a link looking like a button. Unless you have some other issues would you please accept this answer and upvote?